Interpolated values works. But not in logaritmic scale?
I'm using Octave 9.2.0
Could somebody please explain why an interpolated value (in which I get the X and Y coordinates) will now show correctly when presenting the data in logarithmic scale?
Its only the presented data thats in logarithmic scale.
Example:

The X and Y are in linear scale and the found places where the green line crosses the blue lines are working great. Even if you zoom in you can see that they are correct. But its hard do visualize. Hence, I want the Y axis to be in logarithmic scale.
But then the found points will not be correct anymore.
Example (semilogy plot)

It becomes even more obvious if I zoom in on the semilogy plot.

If I zoom in on the normal linear plot function you can see that its spot on.

I fail to understand how this problem can occur since its only the presentation of the data thats different. Is this a bug in Octave or am I missing something?
UPDATE!
Values
x_border=[89.851, 89.381, 88.206, 84.483, 76.524, 63.118, 48.013, 32.873, 20.891];
y1_limit = [950.64, 988.06, 238.63, 333.22, 902.78, 282.25, 776.69, 993.59, 891.05];
y2_limit = [2091.4, 2173.7, 524.99, 733.09, 1986.1, 620.95, 1708.7, 2185.9, 1960.3];
y3_limit = [5.2596e+06, 5.0604e+06, 2.0953e+07, 1.5005e+07, 5.5385e+06, 1.7715e+07, 6.4376e+06, 5.0323e+06, 5.6113e+06];
measured_y=[435.18, 1610.4, 7327.3, 39667, 2.2852e+05, 1.2228e+06, 5.4267e+06, 1.6834e+07, 3.5808e+07];

limit1_pts(1), limit1_pts(2) = [89.638, 967.59];
limit2_pts(1), limit2_pts(2) = [89.291, 2047.6];
limit3_pts(1), limit3_pts(2) =[46.819, 6.3267e+06];

plot for logaritmic scale
figure(999);
clf;
semilogy(x_border, y1_limit,'-.','linewidth',1,'color','b');
hold on;
semilogy(x_border, y2_limit,'-','linewidth',1,'color','b');
hold on;
semilogy(x_border, y3_limit,'-.','linewidth',1,'color','b');
hold on;
semilogy(x_border,measured_y,'-','linewidth',1,'color','g');
hold on;
semilogy(limit1_pts(1), limit1_pts(2),'*','linewidth',3,'color','r');
hold on;
semilogy(limit2_pts(1), limit2_pts(2),'x','linewidth',3,'color','r');
hold on;
semilogy(limit3_pts(1), limit3_pts(2),'*','linewidth',3,'color','r');
hold on;

The same plot for linear is:
figure(999);
clf;
plot(x_border, y1_limit,'-.','linewidth',1,'color','b');
hold on;
plot(x_border, y2_limit,'-','linewidth',1,'color','b');
hold on;
plot(x_border, y3_limit,'-.','linewidth',1,'color','b');
hold on;
plot(x_border,measured_y,'-','linewidth',1,'color','g');
hold on;
plot(limit1_pts(1), limit1_pts(2),'*','linewidth',3,'color','r');
hold on;
plot(limit2_pts(1), limit2_pts(2),'x','linewidth',3,'color','r');
hold on;
plot(limit3_pts(1), limit3_pts(2),'*','linewidth',3,'color','r');
hold on;


You should provide your code, so we can provide a solution, otherwise we don't have stackoverflow valid posts. Mathematically however, it appears you have a set a points, that are connected by straight line segments, both in the linear and the log scale. But the line segment in the linear scale would appear as a curve in the log plot, the linear segment in the log plot is not the correct representation of the segment that resulted in the intersection point.

Check out this very simple example: what happens when you apply log (base 10) to y (equivalent to what happens in the log plot) to a straightforward intersection problem in the following three images img1,img2, img3. The orange dot is (x = 2, y = 2) in the first one, and (x = 2, y = log(2)) in the other two.

You are correct. I've added the data for the plots. I only wondered if this was a general flaw in Octave or if I missed a setting. I agree that if one of the x or y coordinates turnes into logaritmicscale that that would be troublesome. But I still fail to understand how this could happen if only the presented values are listed in logaritmic scale. To me thats quite peculiar.

As I explained in the comments, and also was by Chris Luengo in his post,
the fact that in a semi-log plot the lines don't appear to intersect in the right point is
an artifact of semilogy: the log plot draws linear segments between the points,
but in your application the linear segments are correct only with the linear axis.
With the log axis the same segments should be represented as curves, but semilogy
doesn't know how to do that. Also, as we'll see, those curves don't look very nice,
Here's an approach that will show the log plot as it should, if the segments connecting
the points are an essential part of the application, as they seem to be in your case:
For the four lines, (x_border, y1_limit), (x_border, y2_limit), (x_border, y3_limit)
and (x_border, measured_y) I'll intercalate NPlus = 100 new points between each two
successive points, using linear interpolation between those two points (there will
be about 800 points on each line now). Then just plot/semilogy the finer data instead of
the original data: we'll see the lines transforming to curves and the intersections will
now match:
x_border = [89.851, 89.381, 88.206, 84.483, 76.524, 63.118, 48.013, 32.873, 20.891];
y1_limit = [950.64, 988.06, 238.63, 333.22, 902.78, 282.25, 776.69, 993.59, 891.05];
y2_limit = [2091.4, 2173.7, 524.99, 733.09, 1986.1, 620.95, 1708.7, 2185.9, 1960.3];
y3_limit = [5.2596e+06, 5.0604e+06, 2.0953e+07, 1.5005e+07, 5.5385e+06, 1.7715e+07, 6.4376e+06, 5.0323e+06, 5.6113e+06];
measured_y=[435.18, 1610.4, 7327.3, 39667, 2.2852e+05, 1.2228e+06, 5.4267e+06, 1.6834e+07, 3.5808e+07];

NPlus = 100;
xi = [x_border(1)];
y1i = [y1_limit(1)];
y2i = [y2_limit(1)];
y3i = [y3_limit(1)];
myi = [measured_y(1)];
for i = 1:length(x_border)-1
    nx = length(xi);
    xi(nx) = []; y1i(nx) = []; y2i(nx) = []; y3i(nx) = []; myi(nx) = [];

    xi = cat(2, xi, linspace(x_border(i), x_border(i+1), NPlus+2));
    y1i = cat(2, y1i, linspace(y1_limit(i), y1_limit(i+1), NPlus+2));
    y2i = cat(2, y2i, linspace(y2_limit(i), y2_limit(i+1), NPlus+2));
    y3i = cat(2, y3i, linspace(y3_limit(i), y3_limit(i+1), NPlus+2));
    myi = cat(2, myi, linspace(measured_y(i), measured_y(i+1), NPlus+2));
endfor

limit1_pts = [89.638, 967.59];
limit2_pts = [89.291, 2047.6];
limit3_pts =[46.819, 6.3267e+06];

figure(999);
clf;
semilogy(xi, y1i,'-.','linewidth',1,'color','b');
hold on;
semilogy(xi, y2i,'-','linewidth',1,'color','b');
hold on;
semilogy(xi, y3i,'-.','linewidth',1,'color','b');
hold on;
semilogy(xi, myi,'-','linewidth',1,'color','g');
hold on;
semilogy(limit1_pts(1), limit1_pts(2),'*','linewidth',3,'color','r');
hold on;
semilogy(limit2_pts(1), limit2_pts(2),'x','linewidth',3,'color','r');
hold on;
semilogy(limit3_pts(1), limit3_pts(2),'*','linewidth',3,'color','r');
hold on;


The result is pretty ugly, but those funny looking arcs are the correct representation
with the log y axis of the lines connecting the points with the linear axis. Actually I
haven't done any calculation, I just added evenly distributed points on the segments
for the purpose of showing how the original points are connected.
If we do the same with the linear axis, there is no change to the plot, the result is exactly
the same as before adding the points:
figure(999);
clf;
plot(xi, y1i,'-.','linewidth',1,'color','b');
hold on;
plot(xi, y2i,'-','linewidth',1,'color','b');
hold on;
plot(xi, y3i,'-.','linewidth',1,'color','b');
hold on;
plot(xi, myi,'-','linewidth',1,'color','g');
hold on;
plot(limit1_pts(1), limit1_pts(2),'*','linewidth',3,'color','r');
hold on;
plot(limit2_pts(1), limit2_pts(2),'x','linewidth',3,'color','r');
hold on;
plot(limit3_pts(1), limit3_pts(2),'*','linewidth',3,'color','r');
hold on;


Nice demonstration of what happens to straight lines in a log plot! Also, nice demonstration of why linear interpolation is often not good enough.

Excellent explanation. I thinkntyat makes everything very clear.

This happens because the plot you show is composed of a set of points with a straight line between them. If you use linear interpolation, then the computed points exactly match the straight lines in the linear-scale plot. But in a logarithmic plot, the straight lines do not match the linear interpolation. A straight line in a linear plot becomes a curve in a logarithmic plot, and your interpolated point is on such a straight line in the linear plot.
The straight lines in the plots are approximations of what your function does in between sample points.
The solution is to add the interpolated point to your data. Then you guarantee that the plot exactly goes through that point.
An alternative is to increase the sampling density of your data, making the error in the logarithmic plot smaller.
